# type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index' while getting media fields using the instagram API

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart

i'm trying to get media fields from the instagram api and i'm getting this error

```
type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'
```

here's **Homepage.dart** :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get_storage/get_storage.dart';
import 'package:insta_details/models/data.dart';
import 'package:insta_details/utils/custom_dio_mixin.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static String id = "HomePage";

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with CustomDioMixin {
  bool loading = true;
  bool error = false;
  late Media media;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: loading
            ? const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              )
            : error
                ? const Center(
                    child: Text('An error has occurred!'),
                  )
                : ListView.builder(
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) => MediaWidget(
                      media: media,
                    ),
                  ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> getData() async {
    try {
      final storage = GetStorage();
      final token = storage.read("accessToken");
      Media? media;

      final response = await dio.get(
        'https://graph.instagram.com/me/media?fields=id,caption,media_url,timestamp&access_token=$token',
      );
      print("get data response => ${response.statusCode} ${response.data}");

      Media mediadata = Media.fromJson(response.data);
      print(mediadata);
    } catch (e) {
      print("get data failed");
      print(e);
      setState(() {
        error = true;
      });
    } finally {
      setState(() {
        loading = false;
      });
    }
  }
}

class MediaWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Media media;
  const MediaWidget({Key? key, required this.media}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.builder(
      gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
      ),
      itemCount: 6,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Image.network(media.mediaUrl);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

and here **data.dart** :

```
class Media {
  Media({
    required this.id,
    required this.caption,
    required this.mediaUrl,
    required this.timestamp,
  });

  String id;
  String caption;
  String mediaUrl;
  String timestamp;

  factory Media.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Media(
        id: json["data"]["id"] as String,
        caption: json["data"]["caption"] as String,
        mediaUrl: json["data"]["media_url"] as String,
        timestamp: json["data"]["timestamp"] as String,
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "caption": caption,
        "media_url": mediaUrl,
        "timestamp": timestamp,
      };
}
```

and **the log** :

```
I/flutter ( 5699): get data response => 200 {data: [{id: 18106429915287733, caption: cabin in the woods, media_url: https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.29350-15/272751472_358111429123560_6575694365508668882_n.jpg?_nc_cat=100&ccb=1-5&_nc_sid=8ae9d6&_nc_ohc=0omRv4cUGtwAX8bbmC7&_nc_ht=scontent.cdninstagram.com&edm=ANo9K5cEAAAA&oh=00_AT_fqBkL5ykJXWRj7Rcy4nCnyuXEKh-8o0TX9FJkJ4dcfQ&oe=61FD881A, timestamp: 2022-01-27T11:15:07+0000}, {id: 17917394609104775, caption: Truck, media_url: https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.29350-15/272701475_1080001635904581_1705933746471766077_n.jpg?_nc_cat=107&ccb=1-5&_nc_sid=8ae9d6&_nc_ohc=ZfSpeg7rHn4AX89PW0c&_nc_ht=scontent.cdninstagram.com&edm=ANo9K5cEAAAA&oh=00_AT_Qbj7zOH-UEzplA9mdIrCHaeb9EBBuz1RjKJclN9Q2RA&oe=61FE9898, timestamp: 2022-01-27T11:14:26+0000}, {id: 17921627228176014, caption: Gaara, media_url: https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.29350-15/272660463_892749041374464_5507853711157520506_n.jpg?_nc_cat=101&ccb=1-5&_nc_sid=8ae9d6&_nc_ohc=va5seINOs-4AX9vOy4L&_nc_ht=scontent.cdninst
I/flutter ( 5699): get data failed
I/flutter ( 5699): type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'
```

**my JSON response** :

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "id": "18106429915287733",
        "caption": "cabin in the woods",
        "media_type": "IMAGE",
        "media_url": "https://scontent-iad3-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.29350-15/272751472_358111429123560_6575694365508668882_n.jpg?_nc_cat=100&ccb=1-5&_nc_sid=8ae9d6&_nc_ohc=xXGDvxMsycAAX_U_-55&_nc_ht=scontent-iad3-1.cdninstagram.com&edm=ANo9K5cEAAAA&oh=00_AT-EuNnLxrBSNirBOl1prRXlHepdhQqUjYRBEv3Zh_Ld6Q&oe=61FD881A",
        "username": "parekchampl",
        "timestamp": "2022-01-27T11:15:07+0000"
    },
    {
        "id": "17917394609104775",
        "caption": "Truck",
        "media_type": "IMAGE",
        "media_url": "https://scontent-iad3-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.29350-15/272701475_1080001635904581_1705933746471766077_n.jpg?_nc_cat=107&ccb=1-5&_nc_sid=8ae9d6&_nc_ohc=ZfSpeg7rHn4AX_J_eQs&_nc_ht=scontent-iad3-1.cdninstagram.com&edm=ANo9K5cEAAAA&oh=00_AT92hbhb0XK56kxC-_e8kpM6QFLazDH0TDCfdIdEIpNinw&oe=61FC9E58",
        "username": "parekchampl",
        "timestamp": "2022-01-27T11:14:26+0000"
    },
    {
        "id": "17921627228176014",
        "caption": "Gaara",
        "media_type": "IMAGE",
        "media_url": "https://scontent-iad3-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.29350-15/272660463_892749041374464_5507853711157520506_n.jpg?_nc_cat=101&ccb=1-5&_nc_sid=8ae9d6&_nc_ohc=va5seINOs-4AX_SB6jL&_nc_ht=scontent-iad3-1.cdninstagram.com&edm=ANo9K5cEAAAA&oh=00_AT8rviJ6wbaT0yF1Hq2VprtnQ-W0rARS5oxIr52MIhC0Rw&oe=61FD720B",
        "username": "parekchampl",
        "timestamp": "2022-01-27T11:13:42+0000"
    },
    {
        "id": "18024346318348836",
        "caption": "Marceline",
        "media_type": "IMAGE",
        "media_url": "https://scontent-iad3-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.29350-15/272807293_686124672409566_4991399943515126026_n.jpg?_nc_cat=106&ccb=1-5&_nc_sid=8ae9d6&_nc_ohc=JMfTMSD_1c8AX-m5WDx&_nc_ht=scontent-iad3-1.cdninstagram.com&edm=ANo9K5cEAAAA&oh=00_AT_P38eDVtcqEYL053wGPkLjhHStLCh7_fgFnCg4LcH1yA&oe=61FD1F82",
        "username": "parekchampl",
        "timestamp": "2022-01-27T11:13:02+0000"
    },
    {
        "id": "17859174368680579",
        "caption": "uchiha shisui",
        "media_type": "IMAGE",
        "media_url": "https://scontent-iad3-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.29350-15/272721151_749467822692662_5191995429373550055_n.jpg?_nc_cat=111&ccb=1-5&_nc_sid=8ae9d6&_nc_ohc=01A68vtgY-kAX-ux6iB&_nc_ht=scontent-iad3-1.cdninstagram.com&edm=ANo9K5cEAAAA&oh=00_AT9oWtK9VWV8j3c8Ij2YXctIpuh9sC-NJO1BLCwFObDDSA&oe=61FE0B03",
        "username": "parekchampl",
        "timestamp": "2022-01-27T11:12:35+0000"
    },
    {
        "id": "17917757036265369",
        "caption": "Son and Father",
        "media_type": "IMAGE",
        "media_url": "https://scontent-iad3-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.29350-15/272660947_1107548556714461_1575953024252145708_n.jpg?_nc_cat=100&ccb=1-5&_nc_sid=8ae9d6&_nc_ohc=Mzj5Wp9sv_oAX_2Z4Nv&_nc_ht=scontent-iad3-1.cdninstagram.com&edm=ANo9K5cEAAAA&oh=00_AT8Ywp3DUIemrIoCPajFvivfTG_-AWvEs2fpkngYXUN6Lg&oe=61FE17A1",
        "username": "parekchampl",
        "timestamp": "2022-01-27T11:11:47+0000"
    }
],
"paging": {
    "cursors": {
        "before": "QVFIUnpEcERJTXdYRjd3SVp3MUo2U25UeWhhdlgxQ2xMY0diR2pYVFhCVl9TUUhlM1hqYllKWUpEWXJtYW5RWW41am1Lc3B4U281TU14ZAFoxSVBkMVRsZAkZAB",
        "after": "QVFIUkgtUzExdDNsYzgwUFhGdnRXQlB6N0JkZATVFeU1DVkhzXzduLTF1RklpR1A5MDNMeWVEemtzdE15OVBlYmpYb29mQlVtdDJsX1N2SUcwa2ZAkc21jblZAn"
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/media ,every field is a String

```
  factory Media.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Media(
    id: json["data"]["id"] as String,
    caption: json["data"]["caption"] as String,
    mediaUrl: json["data"]["media_url"] as String,
    timestamp: json["data"]["timestamp"] as String,
  );
```

Or change to something like below:

```
  factory Media.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Media(
    id: int.parse(json["data"]["id"] as String),
    caption: json["data"]["caption"] as String,
    mediaUrl: json["data"]["media_url"] as String,
    timestamp: DateTime.parse(json["data"]["timestamp"] as String),
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of your `data` key is a `List` not a `Map`. Here's an example:

```dart
const responseData =
{
   "data":[
      {
         "id":"18106429915287733",
         "caption":"cabin in the woods",
         "media_type":"IMAGE",
         "media_url":"https://scontent-iad3-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.29350-15/272751472_358111429123560_6575694365508668882_n.jpg?_nc_cat=100&ccb=1-5&_nc_sid=8ae9d6&_nc_ohc=xXGDvxMsycAAX_U_-55&_nc_ht=scontent-iad3-1.cdninstagram.com&edm=ANo9K5cEAAAA&oh=00_AT-EuNnLxrBSNirBOl1prRXlHepdhQqUjYRBEv3Zh_Ld6Q&oe=61FD881A",
         "username":"parekchampl",
         "timestamp":"2022-01-27T11:15:07+0000"
      },
      {
         "id":"17917394609104775",
         "caption":"Truck",
         "media_type":"IMAGE",
         "media_url":"https://scontent-iad3-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.29350-15/272701475_1080001635904581_1705933746471766077_n.jpg?_nc_cat=107&ccb=1-5&_nc_sid=8ae9d6&_nc_ohc=ZfSpeg7rHn4AX_J_eQs&_nc_ht=scontent-iad3-1.cdninstagram.com&edm=ANo9K5cEAAAA&oh=00_AT92hbhb0XK56kxC-_e8kpM6QFLazDH0TDCfdIdEIpNinw&oe=61FC9E58",
         "username":"parekchampl",
         "timestamp":"2022-01-27T11:14:26+0000"
      }
   ]
};

void main() {
  final mediaList = responseData["data"]!.map((entry) => Media.fromJson(entry))
      .toList();
  for (var media in mediaList) {
    print(media.id);
  }
}

class Media {
  Media({
    required this.id,
    required this.caption,
    required this.mediaUrl,
    required this.timestamp,
  });

  int? id;
  String caption;
  String mediaUrl;
  String timestamp;

  factory Media.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Media(
      id: int.tryParse(json["id"]),
      caption: json["caption"],
      mediaUrl: json["media_url"],
      timestamp: json["timestamp"],
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id.toString(),
        "caption": caption,
        "media_url": mediaUrl,
        "timestamp": timestamp,
      };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On your model class `id` is nullable int, but you are receiving `id` as String.

You can typecast string to int On your `Media.fromJson`, while the `id` accept null value, if something wrong happen `id` will get null value.

```dart
  factory Media.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Media(
        id: int.tryParse(json["data"]["id"]),
```

And for `toJson` pass id as String

```dart
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id.toString(),
```

More about [`int.tryParse`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.0.0/dart-core/int/tryParse.html).

Comment: Why use the tryParse if the id will never be null or bad format?

Comment: Yap null for bad format, just extra check, because we aren't handling backend. If the string contains other than numeric digits, it will fail to typecast. For `122a`, it can't be int you can check more [here](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.0.0/dart-core/int/tryParse.html)